# How to calculate maximum rpm for a wheel?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, wheels

I have a DC motor with a rated rpm of 2750. At max rpm, the rubber wheel that I've attached to it is pulling itself apart (literally, the rubber is being pulled away from the central hub due to the centrifugal force). How can I know before purchasing a new wheel weather it will be able to handle this rpm? Is there a way to estimate this or do I need a spec sheet? I haven't seen any wheels that have a spec sheet.

Comment: Can't really help wthout more detail. "Wheel" is super vague. There are hundreds if not thousands of different kinds of wheels all specified differently for different things. Generally though, I can't think of any applications where something is being moved by  a wheel with tires has to spin at 2750RPM. Maybe landing wheels on the space shuttle.

Comment: I can't find the exact model but it's similar to this one: https://www.tractorsupply.com/tsc/product/martin-wheel-8x175-light-duty-plastic-wheel-1-2-in-bore-1-3-8-in-offset-hub-diamond-tread

Comment: and the motor: https://www.amazon.com/ColouredPeas-Electric-2750RPM%EF%BC%89-scooters-modified/dp/B0823RDP5C/ref=sr_1_12?dchild=1&keywords=24vdc+motor&qid=1621402722&s=industrial&sr=1-12

Comment: It doesn't have to spin that fast. But I don't have a speed controllers so I was hoping to find a sturdy wheel.

Comment: Most land wheels are not going to be designed to run anywhere near that speed so no specs. Maybe single molded wheels?

Comment: Btw the **https://www.tractorsupply.com/tsc/product/martin-wheel-8x175-light-duty-plastic-wheel-1-2-in-bore-1-3-8-in-offset-hub-diamond-tread** does not work (I get an access denied in my browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't need the wheel to spin that fast, what you could do is use a gear with a very high gear ratio.

You can easily get a gear ratio of 10 for any size of commercially available DC motors, which would reduce the rotational velocity to the wheel to about 300 rpm. Than would reduce the forces by approximately 100 times (centrifugal forces are proportional to $\omega^2$)